# Hard and medium constraints and relationship between them in OptaPlanner

Tags: optaplanner

Is it possible that OptaPlanner will decide to satisfy number of medium constraints instead of hard constraint? For example we have situation when planner has two ways to choose, one to violate one hard constraint but satisfy x medium constraints and second to violate x medium but satisfy one hard constraint. Is there any possibility that planner will choose the first option? Or contraints with higher priority can't be changed by lower priority constraints under any circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

No. If you want to have that behavior, use the same **score level** (hard I presume) for both constraints and use **score weights** to determine when it's ok the violate 1 to satisfy x of the other.

Also see docs between difference score level and score weight.